# Null pointer Exception at HomeActivity.java

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

- I am getting a null pointer exception at HomeActivity.java.I couldn't
  able to find the error.
- I tried to get the list of videos with the help of `channel user name`
  that was placed in `strings.xml`.

**LogCat:**

```
D/AndroidRuntime(1695): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(1695): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1695): Process: com.grace.view, PID: 1695
E/AndroidRuntime(1695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.grace.view/com.grace.view.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at com.grace.view.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(1695):     ... 11 more
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
 public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener, VideoListFragment.OnVideoSelectedListener{

    // create object of ActionBar and VideoListFragment
    ActionBar actionBar;
    VideoListFragment videoListFrag;

    int selectedItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        actionBar=getActionBar();

      // add channel list array to actionbar spinner
       Context context = getActionBar().getThemedContext(); ----->Null pointer Exception
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.channel_name,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       list.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

     // remove actionbar title and add spinner to actionbar

        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
     // getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);

    }

    // create option menu
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        selectedItem = itemPosition;

        // create object of VideoListFragment and send data position to that fragment
        videoListFrag = new VideoListFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", itemPosition);
        videoListFrag.setArguments(bundle);

        // call video list fragment with new data
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, videoListFrag, "VIDEO_LIST_FRAGMENT")
        .commit();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSelected(String ID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // call player page to play selected video
        Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PlayerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("id", ID);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.grace.view"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.3.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.grace.view.HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"           
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.grace.view.PlayerActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**strings.xml:**

```
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string-array name="channel_name">
        <item >The Father House</item>

    </string-array>
    <string-array name="channel_username">
        <item >TheJesudian</item>

    </string-array>
```

Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: Which line is the line 35 of HomeActivity?

Comment: this line `Context context = getActionBar().getThemedContext();` I mentioned there also.

Comment: @stealthjong how to verify it.it shows null pointer exception

Comment: remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`  this line from Manifest.xml file and try again

Comment: @stealthjong after done that I could saw this line only in debug `08-19 03:20:26.697: D/AndroidRuntime(1861): Shutting down VM`.

Comment: is it still getting NPE?

Comment: @YograjShinde After removing that line I am not getting that exception.But I didn't get the videos from channel user name.Output shows blank

Comment: @NarutoShupident your getting NPE because of that line on Manifest.xml file and you are not getting o/p its other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this line

```
Context context = getActionBar().getThemedContext(); ----->Null pointer Exception
```

And in your Adapter class just use this

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(HomeActivity.this, R.array.channel_name,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
list.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: after done that.I am getting a null pointer exception at this line         `getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: @NarutoShupident If you need to use Action bar in your Home Activity then you must remove this android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" from manifest file.

Comment: yes I tried what you said.After removing that line I am not getting that exception.But I didn't get the videos from channel user name.Output shows blank

Comment: For that you need to check your response and url if there is data or not.

Comment: Check video id which you'r passing is not null and response and url all things which you have passed. If any of them will be null then you can't get your data.

Comment: Thank you for this.Suddenly net wasn't worked for me.that's why I couldn't able to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before `setContentView`

Answer (score 0):

You are using theme with NoTitleBar  `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

add this in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        // do nothing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This wasn't work for me.Again I am getting the same stacktrace error